# How to save a sheet array to PDF with a specific sheet order

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba

I have a Workbook with multiple sheets which I want to select and convert to a single PDF file.

I have written the following code which works fine and creates the file:

```
Sub Print_Project_Report_To_PDF

    Dim FilePathandName As String
    MyDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) - 1, 1), "mmmm yyyy")
    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    MyFile = "Project Progress Report - " & MyDate & ".pdf"
    FilePathandName = MyPath & MyFile

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("PR_COVER_PAGE", "PR_SUMMARY", _
    "PR_PROJECT_DETAILS", "PR_INTERNAL RESOURCES", "PR_TIME", _
    "PR_REVENUE_FORECAST_SUMMARY", "PR_ORIGINAL_REVENUE_FORECAST", _
    "PR_ACTUAL_REVENUE_FORECAST", "PR_COSTS", "PR_ISSUES", "MONTHLY FINANCIAL    REPORT", _
    "PG-SC_COVER_LETTER", "PG-SC_CLAIM_SUMMARY", "PG-SC_TRADE", "PG-SC_HYDRAULICS", _
    "PG-SC_MECHANICAL", "PG-SC_MEDICAL_GASES", "PG-SC_ELECTRICAL", "PG-SC_VARIATION", _
    "PG-SC_MONTHLY_CASHFLOW", "PG-MH_COVER_LETTER", "PG-MH_CLAIM_SUMMARY", _
    "PG-MH_TRADE", "PG-MH_HYDRAULICS", "PG-MH_MECHANICAL", "PG-MH_MEDICAL_GASES", _
    "PG-MH_ELECTRICAL", "PG-MH_VARIATION", "PG-MH_MONTHLY_CASHFLOW", "CLIENT_COVER", _
    "CLIENT_SUMMARY", "CLIENT_ISSUES")).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePathandName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Select

End Sub
```

The problem is that the PDF file is not created with the sheets in order which I have specified in the array.  They are in the order which they appear in the Workbook (Left to right). It correctly only includes the sheets I want but not in the order i want.

I dont want to change the order of the sheets in the Workbook either because it is setup in a specific, progressive way.

Can anyone help me with code which will allow me to be specific with the order of the sheets when the document is published?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rearrange the sheets in the order that you want and then once the printing is done, close the workbook "WITHOUT" saving and hence your setup remains as it is :)

Comment: OR create a new workbook and copy the relevant sheet in the required order and then print that workbook. Once the printing is done, close the newly created workbook without saving...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SiddharthRout in first idea/comment below the question. However, in quite similar situation when I print complicated PowerPoint presentation I use

[PDFCreator application](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)

At the first step I run that software and set 'stop printing' option. Than you could send to that software (in the way you print worksheet) each worksheet separately which would be separate document stacked in the list in the right order at the beginning. Using special feature you can match them into one document then and print it. It's very useful and quite reliable solution.

Comment: Yes, a bit, there are three manual steps- 'launch & stop printing' in PDFCreator, than print Sheets with VBA automation, 'merge documents' in PDFCreator

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample VBA code how copy the current workbook into a temp file and reorder a list of sheets. Use such a routine before printing:

```
Sub CopyAndReorder()
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\TEMP\XXXX.XLS"
    Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\XXXX.XLS")
    ReorderSheets wbCopy
End Sub

Sub ReorderSheets(wb As Workbook)
    Dim shNames As Variant, shName As Variant, sh As Worksheet
    shNames = Array("Table3", "Table2", "Table1")
    For Each shName In shNames
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(shName)
        sh.Move After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Next
End Sub
```

(You have to adapt this code snippet to your needs, of course, use a better temp file name, delete the new file afterwards, provide the list of sheets from outside, etc, but I think you get the idea).